# Can a PFC work without feedback?

Tags: flyback, power-factor-correction

I want to test my PFC using MC33262. How can I be sure that it works? I see any signal on GD pin, yet I powered it correctly with 10-12 Vin the Vcc pin.

Vac = 230 Vrms

Does a PFC emit a frequency by default without feedback?

The doc said nothing about how the output signal is when the PFC isn't supplied correctly.

[image: schematic]

I will put optocoupler and TL431 in the second side to isolate the first and second side, but I want to test if this circuit can work.

The PFC datasheet is here :
https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc34262-d.pdf

Comment: *I see any signal on GD pin* - does not compute... *The doc said anything about* - does not compute. Also, what is the GD pin. The chip and data sheet have a GND pin - is this what you mean?

Comment: Sorry GD is for the stm pfc, thid id the drive output pin.

Comment: You certainly won't see any signal if you forget to connect GND. You should connect all the other pins, then see if it works.

Comment: I did't represent it, I have connected all pins, however I don(t see any signal on drive output pin, I suspect the current sens input. Thank you for all answers.

Comment: The circuit diagram doesn't show any connections to the pins except for Mult, Vcc and GD. If you are having a problem with a circuit you should show the actual circuit. I think a PFC cannot possibly work without *reliably* feedback, so I am wondering why that is your question. Which feedback is missing? Which feedback is not missing?

Comment: Ok, sorry I hope I will be more clear, all pin of the pfc are connected, however there is no signal in the driver output and also no voltage in the output of transformer SMPS, I change the resistor of the sense current pin, 3.3 ohms to 0.5 ohms, I think it works but I did a mistake because the NMOS is brroken, in my opinion the pfc worked and gives an order to the NMOS to be close, my NMOS support a max current of 0.3 A , that's why it is broken, I will review my calculations.

Comment: `all pin of the pfc are connected` This is meaningless to everyone here unless you show a **complete** schematic. Full stop. You could have inserted the schematic of your circuit into your post in the time period you spent while posting comments.

Comment: NFET got too hot ?  What is the rated RdsOn?  < 1 Ohm?  That gives you about 0.1% loss compared to load.  GD signals needs some feedback current and voltage to compute Vg=GD to track sine voltage with PWM on LC.   What is different on your design from known good reference design?

Comment: Rdson in equal to 9.3  ohms,  @TonyStewartEE75
 **What is different on your design from known good reference design**   : I don't understand your question

Comment: Did you do a thermal loss budget analysis?   **None of the examples in the datasheet use a FET with RdsOn > 1ohm**

Comment: No, I didn't do it, thank you

Comment: Why didn't you link to the datasheet?

Comment: What do you means ? Why I didn't add the datasheet link ? I add it below

Comment: As it is now it has feedback through the resistive divider at the output. Look in the datasheet, you're linking it in your OP. On page 1 it clearly shows the internal schematic having the multiplier dependent on the feedback input which goes on the inverting input. No feedback means zero output, thus multiplication by zero.

Comment: Ok I have now 400 mV on the output, Vcc = 15 Vrms, the switching frequency is too low, why ?

Comment: @kodi Please make up what is it you want, but when you do, make sure it's clear such that whoever reads the question can provide a clear answer. As it is now it's awfully hazy: you're asking if the PFC can run without feedback, then you're asking if it "emits" a frequency, then you added a schematic where you clearly show feedback, and now you're asking about a low switching frequency. If you got downvotes and closing votes it's because the way all of this is perceived is: "I don't care about you, you must answer me whatever I want to ask", which is disconsiderate, at best.

Comment: thank you,,I know that the whole is not clear, the question has  evolved depending on answers, I will have to answer it to close the question.

Comment: Your output is floating relative to the main circuit. I assume the bottom of the 135K should connect to ground .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PFC cannot work without feedback:

[image]

As you can see, the FeedBack pin is linked to the inverting input of AOP, this pin is used to track the output voltage value in order to adjust the response.

Answer (score 1):

Feedback does not work with output "ground" not connected to system ground.

[image]